# Variable Variable for $_GET

Tags: php, variables

i have following code.

```
$hello = "World";
$test = "hello";
echo $$test;
```

When I execute this I get as result: World

So far as good

But when I use a reserved variable, for example $_GET it doesn't work.

```
$test = "_GET";
var_dump($$test);
```

Here the result is NULL. Is there a way to get values of a reserved variable throught a variable variable?

Comment: You cannot use [Superglobals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) in that way.

Comment: @Duvdevan Yes you can, but only in the global scope.

Comment: Superglobals are always in the global scope. How can you use them?

Comment: I mean using a variable variable to reference a superglobal only works in the global scope. I.e. `var_dump($$test)` like in the post will work if the code is not in a function or method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Superglobals can only be dereferenced by variable variables in the global scope. The fact you can't get it to work seems to indicate that your code is in a function/method. In this case, you can use the `$GLOBALS` superglobal:

```
function foo() {
    $str = '_GET';
    var_dump($GLOBALS[$str]);
}

foo();
```